# Finding variance using convolution formula, gamma function

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, actuarial-science

> A company has two electric generators. The time until failure for each generator follows an exponential distribution with mean $10$. The company will begin using the second generator immediately after the first one fails. What is the variance of the total time that the generators produce electricity?

**My attempt:**

Let $S$ be the time until the first generator fails and $T$ be the time until the second generator fails. Let $X=S+T$. Then $Var(X) = E[X^2]- (E[X])^2$.

Finding the pdf of $X$ using the convolution formula:

$$f_X(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{10}e^{-s/10} \cdot \frac{1}{10}e^{(s-x)/10} \; ds = \frac{x\cdot e^{-x/10}}{100}$$

Now, utilizing the Gamma function:
$$E[X^2] = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3e^{-x/10}}{100} = \frac{10^4 \times \Gamma(4)}{100} = 600$$

$$E[X] = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2e^{-x/10}}{100} = \frac{10^2 \times \Gamma(2)}{100} = 1$$

So, $Var(X) = 599$, which is not even close to the correct answer. Where have I gone wrong?

**Edit:** The mean is supposed to be $20$, as pointed out in the comments, but the issue is that my current calculations are not leading to that.

Comment: If both $S,T$ have a mean of $10$, how could $S+T$ have a mean of $1$?

Comment: @lulu Wow, I really didn't see that that is what I had concluded. I am still not sure what I did incorrectly in computing the mean.

Comment: @lulu If all other calculations are correct, the mean should be $20$ because the correct variance is $200$.

Comment: Of course the mean of $X$ is $20$.  Expectation is linear, so $E[X]=E[S+T]=E[S]+E[T]=10+10=20$.

Comment: Indeed, your integral gives $20$ (though this is needlessly complicated).  See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+x%5E2exp%28-x%2F10%29%2F100+from+0+to+infinity)

Comment: @lulu The question that remains is: where did I go wrong in computing the mean using the method that I used.

Comment: As I say, you integrated incorrectly.  The integral does give $20$, if done correctly.  You should have $\Gamma(3)$ and you lost a power of $10$.  But, really, I wouldn't approach this problem via convolution. It's much easer to just use the mean and variance of the exponential distribution.

Comment: @lulu Ah, I see. That resolved the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1.**  Linearity.

If $X = S+T$ where $S$, $T$ are the random lifetimes of each generator, respectively, then $$\operatorname{Var}[X] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \operatorname{Var}[S] + \operatorname{Var}[T],$$ where 'ind' over the equality sign indicates that the equality holds under the condition that $S$ and $T$ are independent random variables.  Since the variance of an exponentially distributed random variable with mean $\operatorname{E}[S] = \operatorname{E}[T] = \mu$ is $\operatorname{Var}[S] = \operatorname{Var}[T] = \mu^2$, it follows that $\operatorname{Var}[X] = 2\mu^2 = 200.$

**Method 2.** Gamma distribution as a sum of iid exponential distributions.

Since $S, T$ are iid exponential with mean $\mu = 10$, then $X = S + T$ is Gamma with shape $n = 2$ and **scale** $\theta = \mu = 10$.  Specifically, $$f_X(x) = \frac{x^{n-1} e^{-x/\theta}}{\theta^n \Gamma(n)} = \frac{x e^{-x/10}}{100}, \quad x  > 0.$$  Then the $k^{\rm th}$ raw moment of $X$ is $$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[X^k] &= \int_{x=0}^\infty x^k f_X(x) \, dx \\ &= \int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k+1} e^{-x/10}}{10^2} \, dx \\ &= 10^k \Gamma(k+2) \int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x^{(k+2) - 1} e^{-x/10}}{10^{k+2} \Gamma(k+2)} \, dx \\ &= 10^k \Gamma(k+2), \end{align}$$ where in the last equality, we observe that the integrand corresponds to the density of a gamma distribution with shape $k+2$ and scale $10$, thus integrates to $1$.  Consequently, $$\operatorname{E}[X^2] = 6 (10^2), \quad \operatorname{E}[X]^2 = (2(10))^2,$$ and $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = 600 - 400 = 200.$$